# Fill array with nils for when nothing returned from query in ruby (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a model called foo with a date field.

On my index view, I am showing a typical "weekly view" for a specified week. To put the data in my view, I loop through each day of the specified week and query the data one day at time. I do this so that I can make sure to put a NIL on the correct day.

foos_controller.rb

```
for day in 0..6
    foo = Foo.this_date(@date+day.days).first
    @foos[day] = foo
end
```

index.html.haml

```
- for day in 0..6
    %li
        - if @foos[day].nil?
            Create a new foo?
        - else
            Display a foo information here
```

Obviously, there's a lot of things wrong here.

1. I should find someone smart member to tell me how to write a good query so that I only have to do it once.
2. I should not have any if/else in my view

My goal here is to either show the content if the it is there for a particular day or show a "create new" link if not.

thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I have no idea what `this_date` actually does, but I'll assume it's retrieving a record with a specific date from your datastore. Instead of doing 7 queries, you can condense this into one using a date range:

```
Foo.where(date: (@date..(@date + 6.days)))
```

You can tack on a `.group_by(&:date)` to return something similar to the hash you are manually constructing, but using the actual dates as keys instead of the date offset.

To iterate over the dates in the view, I would recommend using `Hash#fetch`, which allows you to define a default return when a key is not present, e.g:

```
hash = { :a => 1, :b => 2 }
hash.fetch(:a){ Object.new } #=> 1
hash.fetch(:c){ Object.new } # #<Object:...>
```

The question now is what object to substitute for `nil`. If you want to avoid using conditionals here, I'd recommend going with the NullObject pattern (you could involve presenters as well but that might be a bit overkill for your situation). The idea here is that you would create a new class to substitute for a missing foo, and then simply define a method called `to_partial_path` on it that will tell Rails how to render it:

```
class NullFoo
  def to_partial_path
    "null_foos/null_foo"
  end
end
```

You'll need to create partials at both `app/views/foos/_foo.html.erb` and `app/views/null_foos/_null_foo.html.erb` that define what to render in each case. Then, in your view, you can simply iterate thusly:

```
<% (@date..(@date + 6.days)).each do |date| %>
  <%= render @foos.fetch(date){ NullDate.new } %>
<% end %>
```

Is this appropriate for your situation? Maybe it's also a bit overkill, but in general, I think it's a good idea to get in the habit of avoid nil checks whenever possible. Another benefit of the NullObject is that you can hang all sorts of behavior on it that handle these situations all throughout your app.